# WSL $PATH is empty when passing commands in one-line

Tags: linux, powershell, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Windows 11, when using WSL 2 (Ubuntu20.04LTS) in-line, using `wsl -- command`, my PATH variable is empty and programs installed are not found.
I'm writing a Powershell script, and I'd like to run linux commands in one line of script, but this PATH issue is preventing me from doing so.

When running WSL using `--`, I get this:

```bash
λ wsl --user vanyle -- echo $PATH

λ wsl --user vanyle -- python
zsh:1: command not found: python
λ wsl -- python
zsh:1: command not found: python
```

But if I first log into WSL, everything works fine.

```bash
λ wsl
WSL-ZSH /mnt/c/Users/vanyle/
λ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib
WSL-ZSH /mnt/c/Users/vanyle/
λ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 25 2022, 14:53:42)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both PowerShell and POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` and `zsh` use symbol `$` to refer to variables.

**Since you want the *WSL-side shell* to interpret variable `$PATH` you must prevent *PowerShell* from expanding it up front**; which you can do by selectively `` ` ``-[escaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) `$` characters or - more simply - by enclosing `$PATH` in a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings):

```bash
wsl --user vanyle -- echo '$PATH'
```

Note: **If you want to pass *multiple* commands and/or need *shell features* such as `>`**, it's simpler to use the **`-e` option** and call your shell executable (e.g. `bash` or `zsh`) *explicitly*, passing it a command line as a *single string* via the `-c` option; e.g.:

```bash
wsl --user vanyle -e bash -c 'echo $PATH; date'
```

Note: Calling a POSIX-compatible shell with the `-c` option for non-interactive execution of a command does *not* cause profile or initialization files such as `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, or `~/.zshrc` - by default this happens only when entering an *interactive* shell session (passing neither a `-c` argument nor a shell-script path).

**To get the same shell environment as in an *interactive* session**, also pass the **`-i` and `-l`** options; e.g.:

```bash
wsl --user vanyle -e zsh -ilc 'echo $PATH; date'
```